# .CSS jquery random

Tags: jquery, css

When I `console.log(newX/Y)` I am able to get the numbers out, but this line can't seem to work:

```
$robo.css('left', newX + 'px') & $robo.css('top', newY + 'px')
```

Is there a way I can randomly spawn my images? As the images continue to appear systematically

```js
setInterval(function () {
      var goodOrBad = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
      var $robo = $('<img>')
      var newX = ($container.width()) * Math.random()
      var newY = ($container.height()) * Math.random()
      // console.log(goodOrBad)
          if (goodOrBad >= 3) {
            $robo.attr('src', 'assets/img/Pepsi.gif')
            $robo.addClass('Decepticons')
            setTimeout(function() { $robo.remove() }, timeoutCount)
            $robo.on('click', function () {
              $(this).remove()
              score++
              $score.text('score : ' + score)
            $robo.css('left', newX + 'px')
            $robo.css('top', newY + 'px')
            })
          } else {
            $robo.attr('src', 'assets/img/bumble.gif-c200')
            $robo.addClass('AutoBots')
            setTimeout(function() { $robo.remove() }, timeoutCount)
            $robo.on('click', function () {
              $(this).remove()
              live--
              $live.text('live : ' + live)
              if (live === 0) {
                alert('Game Over !')
              }
            })
          }
      $robo.appendTo($container)
    }, intervalTime)
```

```css
.Decepticons {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.AutoBots {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Please fix you example (it is not working) and clean up your code, maybe add some comments too.

Comment: You know your calls to `$robo.css()` are *inside* the click handler, despite what the indenting implies? (As an aside, why have your classes got both `position: absolute` and `position: relative`?)

Comment: Not sure what you had in mind here, but you set the values in the main values, but seem to apply them only on click. Did you mean to set the intervals inside the click function?

Comment: semicolons much

Comment: oh yeah ! thanks for correcting me !! i think i need a break lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, not perfect, but I gotta go to bed.

```js
intervalTime = 1500;
timeoutCount = 1000;
$container = $("div");

score = 0;
$score = $("score")

live = 5;
$live = $("life")

setInterval(function () {
      var goodOrBad = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1)
      var $robo = $('<img>')
      var newX = Math.floor(Math.random() * $container.width() + 1) //Here how to get a random number between 1 to the initial width of the container;
      var newY = Math.floor(Math.random() * $container.height() + 1) //Here how to get a random number between 1 to the initial height of the container;
      console.log (newX, newY);
      $("start").remove(); //Had to start with something or the random numbers would be "width of screen" x "1"
      
          if (goodOrBad >= 3) {
            $robo.attr('src', 'http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/transformersprime/images/7/75/Decepticon_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20120711013840')
            $robo.addClass('Decepticons')
            setTimeout(function() { $robo.remove() }, timeoutCount)
            $robo.on('click', function () {
              $(this).remove()
              score++
              $score.text('score : ' + score)
            $container.css('left', newX + 'px').css('top', newY + 'px') //Added it to $container instead because constantly remove the image
            })
          } else {
            $robo.attr('src', 'http://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/thumb/6/6b/Autobot_symbol.png/250px-Autobot_symbol.png')
            $robo.addClass('AutoBots')
            setTimeout(function() { $robo.remove() }, timeoutCount)
            $robo.on('click', function () {
              $(this).remove()
              live--
              $live.text('live: ' + live)
              if (live === 0) {
                alert('Game Over !')
              }
            })
          }
      $robo.appendTo($container)
    }, intervalTime)
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

.Decepticons {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}

.AutoBots {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<score>score: 0</score>
<life>life: 5</life>
<div><img class="start" scr="'http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/transformersprime/images/7/75/Decepticon_Logo.png/revision/latest?cb=20120711013840" /></div>
```